# Setting laravel task scheduler in the docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, cron, task, scheduling

Can anyone help in setting the laravel scheduler in the docker container? I have installed and set up the server using docker. But to setup a cron job(laravel task scheduler) in the docker container, I am getting the issue.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    default-mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl\
    cron

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www


# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www/

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/


# Change current user to www
USER www

ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And My Entrypoint.sh file code this

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the run once job. echo "Docker container has been started"

# Setup a cron schedule
* * * * * php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# This extra line makes it a valid cron" > scheduler.txt

crontab scheduler.txt 
cron -f
```

I am always getting this error when making a container up.

> cron can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid permission denied

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add more details about the issue you are getting so we can help you.

Comment: @theminer3746 Hi, I have added some more details over my question. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe just try `mkdir /var/run` before crontab command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bin folder and in that add file run-scheduler.sh file in which the laravel schedular command is stated which eventually hits this command.

#!/usr/bin/env bash

> while [ true ]
>
> do
>
> php /var/www/artisan schedule:run --verbose --no-interaction &
>
> sleep 60
>
> done

After this declare a entrypoint.sh file in which the start docker command is stated which hits eventually every 60 sec by run-scheduer.sh.
#!/bin/bash

> ./bin/run-scheduler.sh &
>
> docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

Another option whith docker compose:

```
scheduler:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.14
    container_name: scheduler-maderas
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: scheduler-maderas
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
     - ./src:/var/www/
    command: php artisan schedule:work
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).